# wxPython: Pairing Treeview with Notebook Panel

Tags: tabs, treeview, wxpython, tabpanel

How to pairing Treeview with Notebook Panel Items? For example, you click on the treeview item, FLEX01, then the tab of FLEX01 will be selected.

Below is my example code:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python


 import wx
 import gettext

 tview_Items = [
    ["Overview - Job", 
        ["Job Activities"]],
    ["Server",
        ["FLEX01",
        "FLEX02",
        "FLEX03",
        "FLEX03",
        "FLEX04",
        "FLEX05",
        "FLEX06",
        "FLEX07",
        "FLEX08",
        "FLEX09",
        "FLEX10",
        "FLEX11",
        "FLEX12"]
    ]
 ]
```

> ```
> class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
>   def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
>       kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
>       wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
>       self.tree_ctrl = wx.TreeCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.TR_HAS_BUTTONS | wx.TR_LINES_AT_ROOT | wx.TR_DEFAULT_STYLE | wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
>       root = self.tree_ctrl.AddRoot("General")
>       #self.tree_ctrl.Expand(root) # Adding nodes from the data set
>       self.AddTreeNodes(root, tview_Items) # Adding nodes from the data set
>       self.tree_ctrl.ExpandAllChildren(root)  # Expand all the node's children
>       self.notebook_1 = wx.Notebook(self, wx.ID_ANY, style=0)
>       self.panel_JobActivities = wx.ScrolledWindow(self.notebook_1, wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)
>       self.panel_Flex01 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_1, wx.ID_ANY)
>       self.panel_Flex02 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_1, wx.ID_ANY)
>       self.panel_Flex03 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_1, wx.ID_ANY)
>       self.panel_Flex04 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_1, wx.ID_ANY)
>       self.panel_Flex05 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_1, wx.ID_ANY)
>       self.panel_Flex06 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_1, wx.ID_ANY)
>       self.panel_Flex07 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_1, wx.ID_ANY)
>       self.panel_Flex08 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_1, wx.ID_ANY)
>       self.panel_Flex09 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_1, wx.ID_ANY)
>       self.panel_Flex10 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_1, wx.ID_ANY)
>       self.panel_Flex11 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_1, wx.ID_ANY)
>       self.panel_Flex12 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_1, wx.ID_ANY)
>
>       self.__set_properties()
>       self.__do_layout()
>
>       self.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_SEL_CHANGED, self.OnSelfChanged, self.tree_ctrl)
>       self.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_ITEM_ACTIVATED, self.OnActivated, self.tree_ctrl)
>       self.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_ITEM_COLLAPSED, self.OnItemCollapsed, self.tree_ctrl)
>       self.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_ITEM_EXPANDED, self.OnItemExpanded, self.tree_ctrl)
>       # end 
>
>   def __set_properties(self):
>       # begin : MyFrame.__set_properties
>       self.SetTitle(_("Application"))
>       self.SetSize((1070, 772))
>       self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(240, 240, 240))
>       self.tree_ctrl.SetMinSize((200, 709))
>       self.panel_JobActivities.SetMinSize((754, 683))
>       self.panel_JobActivities.SetScrollRate(10, 10)
>       self.notebook_1.SetMinSize((841, 587))
>       # end 
>
>   def __do_layout(self):
>       # begin : MyFrame.__do_layout
>       grid_sizer_1 = wx.FlexGridSizer(1, 2, 2, 2)
>       grid_sizer_1.Add(self.tree_ctrl, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 10)
>       self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.panel_JobActivities, _("Job Activities"))
>       self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.panel_Flex01, _("FLEX 01"))
>       self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.panel_Flex02, _("FLEX 02"))
>       self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.panel_Flex03, _("FLEX 03"))
>       self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.panel_Flex04, _("FLEX 04"))
>       self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.panel_Flex05, _("FLEX 05"))
>       self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.panel_Flex06, _("FLEX 06"))
>       self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.panel_Flex07, _("FLEX 07"))
>       self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.panel_Flex08, _("FLEX 08"))
>       self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.panel_Flex09, _("FLEX 09"))
>       self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.panel_Flex10, _("FLEX 10"))
>       self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.panel_Flex11, _("FLEX 11"))
>       self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.panel_Flex12, _("FLEX 12"))
>       grid_sizer_1.Add(self.notebook_1, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 10)
>       self.SetSizer(grid_sizer_1)
>       grid_sizer_1.AddGrowableRow(0)
>       grid_sizer_1.AddGrowableCol(0)
>       self.Layout()
>
>       self.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_SEL_CHANGED, self.OnSelfChanged, self.tree_ctrl)
>       self.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_ITEM_ACTIVATED, self.OnActivated, self.tree_ctrl)
>       self.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_ITEM_COLLAPSED, self.OnItemCollapsed, self.tree_ctrl)
>       self.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_ITEM_EXPANDED, self.OnItemExpanded, self.tree_ctrl)
>       self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)
>       # end 
>
>   def AddTreeNodes(self, parentItem, items): # Building the tree nodes
>       for item in items:
>           if type(item) == str:
>               self.tree_ctrl.AppendItem(parentItem, item)
>           else:
>               newItem = self.tree_ctrl.AppendItem(parentItem, item[0])
>               self.AddTreeNodes(newItem, item[1])
>
>   def OnSelfChanged(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyFrame.<event_handler>
>       print "OnSelChanged: ", self.GetItemText(event.GetItem())
>
>       for page in range(self.Notebook.GetPageCount()):
>           if page == self.Notebook_1.GetSelection():
>               print self.Notebook_1.Item()
>
>   def OnActivated(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyFrame.<event_handler>
>       print "OnActivated: ", self.GetItemText(event.GetItem())
>
>   def OnItemCollapsed(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyFrame.<event_handler>
>       print "OnItemCollapsed: ", self.GetItemText(event.GetItem())
>
>   def OnItemExpanded(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyFrame.<event_handler>
>       print "OnItemExpanded: ", self.GetItemText(event.GetItem())
>
>   def GetItemText(self, item):
>       if item:
>           return self.tree_ctrl.GetItemText(item)
>       else:
>           return ""
>
>   def OnClose(self, event):
>       dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self,
>           "Do you really want to close this application?",
>           "Confirm Exit", wx.OK|wx.CANCEL|wx.ICON_QUESTION)
>       result = dlg.ShowModal()
>       dlg.Destroy()
>       if result == wx.ID_OK:
>           self.Destroy()
>
> # end of class MyFrame
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>   gettext.install("app")
>
>   app = wx.App(0)
>   frame = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
>   app.SetTopWindow(frame)
>   frame.Show()
>   app.MainLoop()
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You were very very close.   You just need to compare the treectrl text with the notebook tab text, and call SetSelection if it matches.

```
  def OnSelfChanged(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyFrame.<event_handler>
      selected = self.GetItemText(event.GetItem())
      print "OnSelChanged: ", selected

      for page in range(self.notebook_1.GetPageCount()):
          print self.notebook_1.GetPageText(page)
          if self.notebook_1.GetPageText(page) == selected:
              self.notebook_1.SetSelection(page)
```

**In Addtion**  I had to change the names of the tabs of the notebook to match the labels in the treeview.  In your code the treeview has no spaces ("FLEX01") but the notebook tabs have spaces ("FLEX 01").   I got rid of the spaces.   It works.

---

Full working code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import wx
import gettext

tview_Items = [
    ["Overview - Job", 
        ["Job Activities"]],
    ["Server",
        ["FLEX01",
        "FLEX02",
        "FLEX03",
        "FLEX03",
        "FLEX04",
        "FLEX05",
        "FLEX06",
        "FLEX07",
        "FLEX08",
        "FLEX09",
        "FLEX10",
        "FLEX11",
        "FLEX12"]
    ]
 ]
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
      kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
      wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
      self.tree_ctrl = wx.TreeCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.TR_HAS_BUTTONS | wx.TR_LINES_AT_ROOT | wx.TR_DEFAULT_STYLE | wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
      root = self.tree_ctrl.AddRoot("General")
      #self.tree_ctrl.Expand(root) # Adding nodes from the data set
      self.AddTreeNodes(root, tview_Items) # Adding nodes from the data set
      self.tree_ctrl.ExpandAllChildren(root)  # Expand all the node's children
      self.notebook_1 = wx.Notebook(self, wx.ID_ANY, style=0)
      self.panel_JobActivities = wx.ScrolledWindow(self.notebook_1, wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)
      self.panel_Flex01 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_1, wx.ID_ANY)
      self.panel_Flex02 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_1, wx.ID_ANY)
      self.panel_Flex03 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_1, wx.ID_ANY)
      self.panel_Flex04 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_1, wx.ID_ANY)
      self.panel_Flex05 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_1, wx.ID_ANY)
      self.panel_Flex06 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_1, wx.ID_ANY)
      self.panel_Flex07 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_1, wx.ID_ANY)
      self.panel_Flex08 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_1, wx.ID_ANY)
      self.panel_Flex09 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_1, wx.ID_ANY)
      self.panel_Flex10 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_1, wx.ID_ANY)
      self.panel_Flex11 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_1, wx.ID_ANY)
      self.panel_Flex12 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_1, wx.ID_ANY)

      self.__set_properties()
      self.__do_layout()

      self.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_SEL_CHANGED, self.OnSelfChanged, self.tree_ctrl)
      self.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_ITEM_ACTIVATED, self.OnActivated, self.tree_ctrl)
      self.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_ITEM_COLLAPSED, self.OnItemCollapsed, self.tree_ctrl)
      self.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_ITEM_EXPANDED, self.OnItemExpanded, self.tree_ctrl)
      # end 

  def __set_properties(self):
      # begin : MyFrame.__set_properties
      self.SetTitle(_("Application"))
      self.SetSize((1070, 772))
      self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(240, 240, 240))
      self.tree_ctrl.SetMinSize((200, 709))
      self.panel_JobActivities.SetMinSize((754, 683))
      self.panel_JobActivities.SetScrollRate(10, 10)
      self.notebook_1.SetMinSize((841, 587))
      # end 

  def __do_layout(self):
      # begin : MyFrame.__do_layout
      grid_sizer_1 = wx.FlexGridSizer(1, 2, 2, 2)
      grid_sizer_1.Add(self.tree_ctrl, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 10)
      self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.panel_JobActivities, _("Job Activities"))
      self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.panel_Flex01, _("FLEX01"))
      self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.panel_Flex02, _("FLEX02"))
      self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.panel_Flex03, _("FLEX03"))
      self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.panel_Flex04, _("FLEX04"))
      self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.panel_Flex05, _("FLEX05"))
      self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.panel_Flex06, _("FLEX06"))
      self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.panel_Flex07, _("FLEX07"))
      self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.panel_Flex08, _("FLEX08"))
      self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.panel_Flex09, _("FLEX09"))
      self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.panel_Flex10, _("FLEX10"))
      self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.panel_Flex11, _("FLEX11"))
      self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.panel_Flex12, _("FLEX12"))
      grid_sizer_1.Add(self.notebook_1, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 10)
      self.SetSizer(grid_sizer_1)
      grid_sizer_1.AddGrowableRow(0)
      grid_sizer_1.AddGrowableCol(0)
      self.Layout()

      self.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_SEL_CHANGED, self.OnSelfChanged, self.tree_ctrl)
      self.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_ITEM_ACTIVATED, self.OnActivated, self.tree_ctrl)
      self.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_ITEM_COLLAPSED, self.OnItemCollapsed, self.tree_ctrl)
      self.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_ITEM_EXPANDED, self.OnItemExpanded, self.tree_ctrl)
      self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)
      # end 

  def AddTreeNodes(self, parentItem, items): # Building the tree nodes
      for item in items:
          if type(item) == str:
              self.tree_ctrl.AppendItem(parentItem, item)
          else:
              newItem = self.tree_ctrl.AppendItem(parentItem, item[0])
              self.AddTreeNodes(newItem, item[1])

  def OnSelfChanged(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyFrame.<event_handler>
      selected = self.GetItemText(event.GetItem())
      print "OnSelChanged: ", selected

      for page in range(self.notebook_1.GetPageCount()):
          print self.notebook_1.GetPageText(page)
          if self.notebook_1.GetPageText(page) == selected:
              self.notebook_1.SetSelection(page)

  def OnActivated(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyFrame.<event_handler>
      print "OnActivated: ", self.GetItemText(event.GetItem())

  def OnItemCollapsed(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyFrame.<event_handler>
      print "OnItemCollapsed: ", self.GetItemText(event.GetItem())

  def OnItemExpanded(self, event):  # wxGlade: MyFrame.<event_handler>
      print "OnItemExpanded: ", self.GetItemText(event.GetItem())

  def GetItemText(self, item):
      if item:
          return self.tree_ctrl.GetItemText(item)
      else:
          return ""

  def OnClose(self, event):
      dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self,
          "Do you really want to close this application?",
          "Confirm Exit", wx.OK|wx.CANCEL|wx.ICON_QUESTION)
      result = dlg.ShowModal()
      dlg.Destroy()
      if result == wx.ID_OK:
          self.Destroy()

# end of class MyFrame
if __name__ == "__main__":
  gettext.install("app")

  app = wx.App(0)
  frame = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
  app.SetTopWindow(frame)
  frame.Show()
  app.MainLoop()
```